# Move scrollview to original state

Tags: ios

I want to move up the view when the keyboard appears and move the view back when the keyboard disappears. I use an scrollview for this.

I have this almost working. The bug that I have is this:

1. You trigger the keyboard to show
2. You trigger the keyboard to hide

Things are going great so far.

3. You trigger the keyboard to show
4. You trigger the keyboard to hide <-- This doesn't work anymore, but the first time it works perfectly.

The code when the keyboard shows up (this works overtime):

```
func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    var userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let buttonOrigin: CGPoint = btn.frame.origin
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = btn.frame.size.height
    var visibleRect: CGRect = view.frame

    visibleRect.size.height -= keyboardFrame.size.height
    if !visibleRect.contains(buttonOrigin) {
        let scrollPoint = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0.0), y: CGFloat(buttonOrigin.y - visibleRect.size.height + (buttonHeight + 8)))
        scrollView.setContentOffset(scrollPoint, animated: true)
    }
}
```

The code when the keyboard is going to hide (This code works the first time, it doesn't work the second time):

```
func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size

    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

This is how my view looks like:
[image]

Everything needs to move up when the keyboard is showing. Moving up works:

[image]

But when the keyboard disappears it doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: try using this pod `IQKeyboardManagerSwift`is awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this Line
 `let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)`

with

`let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = .zero`

or try This

//MARK:- Keyboard Methods

```
  func keyboardWillOpen(sender:Notification) {

        if let info = sender.userInfo{

            if let keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect{
                let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -keyboardSize.height, 0)


            self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
            }
        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification:Notification) {

        if let info = notification.userInfo {

            if let keyboardSize = info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? CGRect {

            self.scrollView.contentInset = .zero
            self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = .zero

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @da1lbi3 try the updated answer and let me know is it working or not

Comment: Your updated answer doesn't work. Nothing happens on both methods.

Comment: tell me how you open your keyboard this methods only works when your text field is below the keyboard area but if textfield is upper than your keyboard height then they not work

Comment: I have added the view to my question. The keyboard is triggered when I click on the textbox.

Comment: if you try to move button and textfield also move up then add button & textField also in UIScrollview 's contentView and and  change this line ` let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -keyboardSize.height, 0)`  with  ` let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -keyboardSize.height + 100,  0)`  hope this works

Comment: I have updated my answer again to show you what is going wrong.

Comment: Your scroll view is not going up because you add the button and textfield outside the scroll view first of all add a view in scroll view and then add both textfield and button in that view after that my coding work fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139654/discussion-between-gurinder-batth-and-da1lbi3).

Answer (score 0):

I would not bother to scroll the scrollview, but instead move the scrollview itself.

Get the outlet of the scrollview bottom constraint, and, supposing the scrollview is fullscreen, set the  constraint to zero when  the keyboard is hidden, and then set it to the keyboard height (correct value is in the notification of keyboardwillshow).

Pseudo code looks like this :

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.scrollviewBottomConstraint.constant = notification.keyboardheight;
    self.layoutifneeded(); //I suggest you put this in a 0.3 second animation block
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.scrollviewBottomConstraint.constant = 0;
    self.layoutIfNeeded(); //I suggest you put this in a 0.3 second animation block
}
```